# HOW TO PRINT A TO Z ALPHABETS IN QUERY WITHOUT USING TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

HOW TO PRINT A TO Z ALPHABETS IN QUERY WITHOUT USING TABLE

Comment: In Postgres or Oracle?

Comment: Your keyboard is broken: all characters come out as uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, here's one option:

```
SQL> select chr(level + 64) letter
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= ascii('Z') - ascii('A') + 1;

LETTER
----------
A
B
C
D
E
F
<snip>
X
Y
Z

26 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Postgres:

```
select chr(code)
from generate_series(ascii('A'), ascii('Z')) as t(code)
order by code
```

Answer (score 0):

select chr(generate_series(65,97));

**output**
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).